# Querying database for all records in each hour

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, date, datetime

I have a database which stores a snapshot of the temperature every minute. I have an API endpoint for populating an hourly historic temperature bar graph. At the moment, I create an array of hourly periods over 24 hrs as UNIX timestamps, the logic then looks like this:

```
db.Temperature.aggregate('value', 'AVG', {
    where: {
        createdAt: {
            $lt: start,// new Date(UnixStartTime + 3600000) end of the hour for a given start point
            $gt: end// new Date(UnixStartTime)
        },
    },
});
```

The issue with this is that of course if I make the query at 11:30, the 11 O'clock reading is actually everything from `10:30 to 11:30`, where it should be `11:00 to 11:30` and the previous value should be `10:00 to 11:00`.

How can I fix this logic such that the returned values are actually from the correct hour period?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should actually be wrapping the $aggregate into a cron job. This is how a repetitive task is done, exactly when you want it to be done. Have the cron job query every hour of every day.

Two NPM modules both excellent to do the job:

[node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)

[cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)

Using them is fairly easy. Just follow the date and time constructs they use and wrap  your function into the cron job.

This would be the structure in [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('00 00 00 * * *', function() {
    \\do your stuff here
}
```

Comes with Timezones and ability to start the cron immediately.

Comment: Then I would need to store an hourly & daily (and weekly, monthly, annual) value, which isn't really what I want to do. Also, I wouldn't have up to date info on todays "average so far".

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards I may not be clear then on exactly what you need to do, but it sounds to me as if you will need a function to manipulate the timestamp based upon the time the query is requested. My suggestion then would be assessing current time, seeing how long you back you want to run it, (30 or 60 minutes), then creating the correct $gt and $lt. It is possible that [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) will help you in manipulating the times.